# Finding dimensions of field with maximum area.

Tags: calculus

A rectangular field is to be bounded by a fence on three sides and by a straight section of lake on the fourth side. Find the dimensions of the field with maximum area that can be enclosed with M feet of fence.

I’m very stuck on this problem. Here is a photo of the work I have done so far.

[image: here]

Could someone tell me if I’m on the right track and show me where to go from here(

Comment: Yes, you are. You basically have gotten the answer.

Comment: Good job. Now find $l$ (assuming $l$ is a part of fence that is perpendicular to the lake)

Comment: @Vasya would $l$ be $m/4$ ?

Comment: @Ella: yes, of course

Comment: In your equation for the area, $M - 2l$ should be in parentheses.  Everything else is fine.